# How make clang-tidy apply FixItHints sequentially, one after another?

Tags: c++, llvm-clang, clang-tidy

I'm writing clang-tidy check that will move comment in right place like that:

Before:

```
/// comment 1
void func();
void func2(); /// comment 2
void func3(); /// comment 3
```

After:

```
/// comment 1
void func();
/// comment 2
void func2();
/// comment 3
void func3();
```

I'm trying to remove `/// comment 3` and then insert it before `void func3();`.

But at first clang-tidy-check should read comment before `void func3();`. Check reads `/// comment 2` because `/// comment 2` doesn't have time to removed.

How make tidy-check apply fixes in the order in which methods are found?

Answer (score 0):

One simple (or stupid?) trick comes to mind - make your clang-tidy check apply only one fix at a time (i.e finish processing the code after one place to be fixed is matched). Then write a simple python script that would run clang-tidy over and over with your check enabled until it has something to process.
You can get inspired by [run-clang-tidy.py](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/blob/master/clang-tidy/tool/run-clang-tidy.py) but yours would be much simpler of course.